# Julia | Error with Reverse For Loop

Tags: julia

I would like to create an array that goes like this

[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]

I use the following code, that should be right, but I am not getting the result I would like.

```
x = 0

for i in 1:4
   for z in i:1

       x = x + 1
       index[x] = z

   end
end
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the UnitRange, e.g. `1:10` in the absence of an explicit step assumes a step of `1`. The step is not inferred from the direction. Therefore, if you want to go 'backwards' you need to specify a step of '-1', e.g. `10:-1:1`. Otherwise, the result of something like `10:1` corresponds to an empty array, since there is no way to reach '1' from '10' using steps of '+1'.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following one-liner:

```
index = [ n for m in 1:4 for n in m:-1:1 ]
```

If you actually need to pre-allocate `index` for some reason, you can also write the loop out more verbosely like so:

```
m = 4
index = ones(Int, sum(1:m))
c = 1
for m in 1:4
    for n in m:-1:1
        index[c] = n
        c += 1
    end
end
```